# Is there a non-simply-connected space with trivial first homology group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Is there a path connected topological space such that its fundamental group is non-trivial, but its first homology group is trivial?

Since the first homology group of a space is the abelianization of the fundamental group, we are looking for a non-trivial group whose abelianization is trivial. Is there such a group?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A group whose abelianization is trivial is called [perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group), and there are many such groups. In particular, any nonabelian finite simple group is perfect, so $A_5$, for example, is perfect. $A_5$ is in fact the smallest nontrivial perfect group. So any space with fundamental group $A_5$ is an example.

A famous example which almost has fundamental group $A_5$ is [Poincare dodecahedral space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Poincar.C3.A9_homology_sphere). This is a closed $3$-manifold which is the quotient of $S^3$ by an action of the [binary icosahedral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_icosahedral_group), which is an extension of $A_5$, and like $A_5$ is perfect. Any closed $3$-manifold with perfect fundamental group necessarily has the same homology as a sphere, and this showed Poincare that for a $3$-manifold to be a sphere it did not suffice that its homology was the same as a sphere, motivating the fundamental group condition in the statement of the [Poincare conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, for any group $G$ there exists a (path connected) $K(G,1)$, and there are non-trivial groups with trivial abelianization.

Answer (score 10):

This is exactly the type of space that Poincare constructed to show that homology was not enough to distinguish three-manifolds from the three-sphere. He took a dodecahedron and glued opposite faces with a minimal clockwise twist. The resulting space is a *[homology sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere)* --- it has the homology groups of $\Bbb S^3$, but has nontrivial $\pi_1$.